# Control that web page could be loaded only from an specific PC

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

I'm looking for just some orientation about how to control that an ASP.NET web site could be only loaded from specific IP client addresses. I mean: the user is only allowed to load web app from its PC at office, but can not load web app from other PC.

It seems obvious that the login web page should get the IP address or PC name from the client and check with a database query if that IP address plus the userid account match its database record.

However, catching the IP address with

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

could get a IP address distorted by a firewall, NAT or router configuration. So that option is discarded.

Other option that I've heard is about creating a dll file with a name like "license.dll", and store inside that dll file some credential or IP address or serial number. That data plus the userid account have to be stored in database . When user loads the web page, it should read first that dll file and get the credential inside it, make a query to database and match userid account and dll credential. If matching is correct, then web page is loaded.

Is it possible to store some credential in a dll file and make the web page able to read that dll?

**EDIT:**
There is a web app that works in the same way I explained:

[image]

In order to access that web app with userid and password, for the first time, you have to install at your PC a client side certificate and a dll file. After that, you can only access this web app from that PC and is not possible to get access with your userid and password from other PC.

Comment: Can you use client certificates?

Comment: At the moment, I was requested to do it with only program code. If it is impossible or too difficult to do it, then I should talk with server's guys and ask permission for installing client certificates in IIS.

Comment: @CodeMaster, at IIS server it's going to be installed client side certificates. Would you mind giving us some orientation about how could that help in controlling that user can only loaded web app from his IP client address and not from other PC?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a DMZ around the server. Only those machines that are part of the DMZ will be able to connect to the server. Another option is NTML with Windows Authentication. I don't think the IP address solution is a good option.

Comment: I think client side certificate would be the path to follow. I have edited my question and added more references.